# Do monthly contact lenses have to be discarded 30 days from opening them even if they haven't been used?

Tags: eye, contact-lenses

I'm -8.00(OD) & -7.25(OS) and thinking of getting contacts lenses for the very first time. I plan on getting the monthly disposable type. I'll be wearing them once or twice a week mostly when I head out. Since I will be using them maybe 8 times a month, and since they're designed to be used for 30 days, can I keep wearing them till they reach 30 uses, or do I need to dispose them 30 days after I've taken them out of their packaging?

Comment: This is a question for the manufacturer of the lenses since we can't be sure any answer applies equally to all lenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this FAQ](https://www.bauschandlomb.in/faq) *(question 37)*:

> **Does monthly contact lens mean 30 wears?**
>
> Monthly disposable contact lenses should be thrown away precisely 30 days after opening the blister pack, regardless of the number of times you have worn them.

[Here](https://www.allaboutvision.com/buysmart/contacts_lasik.htm) is another article that quotes:

> Also called "extended wear lenses" or "monthly contact lenses," continuous wear lenses are soft contact lenses that are approved by the FDA for up to **30 consecutive days** of continuous day-and-night wear without removal.

So basically, it doesn't matter if you didn't wear the contact lenses as much; **you'll still need to dispose them after 30 days of opening the package**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).